# SQL Trouble using DATEADD to delete records from database

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

```
$datediff = "DELETE FROM table1 * WHERE date = DATEADD(day,-1,CURDATE())";
$link->query($datediff);
```

I am trying to use DATEADD to delete any records in a table in my database that are **one day old from CURDATE**. However, when using the above code I am **not having success in deleting these records**. The dates were put in my database using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

I have tried:
-using 'dd' in place of 'day'
-putting single quotes around the word 'day'
-using alternatives to CURDATE() such as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and GETDATE()

Does anyone have any suggestions of what to try, or see anything I have done wrong to keep this from working? Thank you in advance.

Comment: which rdbms? can't be both

Comment: @Alexander What do you mean by rdbms?

Comment: I'd change the query so it read date between midnight on the day before today and 23:59:59 on the day before today.

Comment: @nickatnite relational database management system. Basically: which database do you have, either MySql or Sql Server. You tagged your question for both, but they are different systems, which you can also read in the explanation of the tag (hover over them).

Comment: @GolezTrol thank you for the explanation. I did not know that. This is pertaining to Sql Server though. I will update the tags to reflect that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use interval

```
DELETE 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE date = (current_timestamp() - INTERVAL 1 day);
```

The second option is [`DATESUB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
DELETE 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE date = DATESUB(current_timestamp(), INTERVAL 1 day);
```

Also, there is no need for `*`

P.S. This answer is for MySQL

Comment: damn... maybe this is MySQL instead of SQL Server. It worked.. Thought for sure it was SQL Server. How can I check?

Comment: what are you using to connect?

Comment: MySQL... I gotcha. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You did not report the types of column called `DATE`. If this columnn is a TIMESTAMP, then your query will not work because the hour, minute, second components of one day before now will not match those of the records. In this case you CAST() or CONVERT() both the column and the comparison value into DATE to get a comparison between the year, month, day components only.

Comment: He did. And that should be a comment

Comment: No, he said CURRENT_TIMESTAMP was used to put the records. Did not say if the type of the column was TIMESTAMP.